# Classifying all bijective transformations of a set $X$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples, transformation

Here we make some set theoretic statements, that, from my understanding are true. If any of the claims are false, please clarify the situation for me with a counter-example.

---

Let $f: A \to A$ be a bijective transformation.

Define, for each $x \in A$ the set $A_x =\{f^n(x) \mid \text{ integer } n \ge 0\}$.

If we call each set $A_x$ a filament, then the theory/notation found in

$\quad$ [Generating the blocks of a partition from a family of filaments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3710324/generating-the-blocks-of-a-partition-from-a-family-of-filaments)

is applicable here.

Before presenting the main theorem, we give an example of a bijective transformation on a set.

[Recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n) for $n \ge 0$ we have the sets ${\displaystyle \mathbb {Z} /n\mathbb {Z} }$.

Let $I$ be a set with a function

$\quad \displaystyle \tau: I \to \{\mathbb {Z} /n\mathbb {Z} \mid n \ge 0\}$

The mapping

$\quad m_{i} \mapsto m_i + 1 \text{ where } m_i \in \tau(i)$

defines a bijective tranformation on the (disjoint) union

$\quad  {\displaystyle \bigsqcup _{i\in I}\,\tau(i)}$

We call such a transformation canonical.

Theorem: Every bijective tranformation on $A$, is, up to a (set) isomorphism, equivalent to a canonical transformation.

**My work**

I've been working towards describing a 'canonical picture' for the proof construction behind the [Schröder-Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem#Proof); the setting here is a simpler instance for the constructive analysis.

If the above passes scrutiny, I plan to provide the (canonical) proof detail for the Schröder-Bernstein theorem.

If the above theory/program has been already been worked out, any references/links would be appreciated.

---

Here is an example (see comment).

Let $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and

$\quad f(1) = 2, f(2) = 1, f(3) = 4, f(4) = 3$

Let

$\quad \displaystyle \tau: \{1,2\}  \to \{\mathbb {Z} /2\mathbb {Z}\}$

be the constant mapping to the set $\mathbb {Z} /2\mathbb {Z} = \{0,1\}$ (the modulo 2 residue number system).

The canonical transformation representing $f$ operates on

$\quad  \displaystyle \bigsqcup _{i\in \{1,2\}}\,\tau(i) = \bigsqcup _{i\in \{1,2\}} \{0,1\}_i$

by mapping $m_i \in \{0,1\}_i$ to $m_i + 1 \in \{0,1\}_i$ (a simple transposition, $0 \leftrightarrow 1$).

Comment: Your "canonical transformation" does not even necessarily carry $\bigsqcup _{i\in I}\,\tau(i)$ to itself. You are assuming that if $m \in\tau(I)$, then $m+1 \in\tau(I)$, but the only requirement on $\tau$ is that it is a function, and that is not enough to guarantee it. Also, the disjoint union is not necessarily a subset of $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ (or just $\Bbb Z_n$, to those of us who dislike unnecessarily cumbersome notations). What makes it *disjoint* is adding indexes to its elements, and those indexes break the definition of $+$, and therefore of your transformation.

Comment: If I understand what your intent is, it seems to me that letting $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and $f : A \to A$ be $$f(1) = 2, f(2) = 1, f(3) = 4, f(4) = 3$$ is a counter-example to your "theorem".

Comment: @PaulSinclair I added an example using your function $f$  (permutation on $\{1,2,3,4\}$).

Comment: Okay - I see where I misunderstood your discription. Both of my comments are wrong. But I won't apologize for it. Did you purposefully sit down and decide "what is the most convoluted and obfuscated way I can describe this simple idea"? I hardly can imagine that if you had, you could have done any better than this.

Answer (score 1):

The trick to proving your theorem is to define $a \sim b$ if and only if there is some $n$ such that $f^n(a) = b$ or $f^n(b) = a$. This is an equivalence relation and the equivalence classes are the loops and $\Bbb Z$ images you are looking for.

Comment: There are many questions on this site about the Schröder-Bernstein theorem. But thanks for the scrutiny you've given this. (+1)

Comment: Two idioms come to mind: $\quad$ Six of one and half a dozen of the other $\quad$ The devil is in the detail